# Generate first/next/prev/last links where api only provides offset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write some code that takes an `offset` value and then generate first/next/prev/last links.

I currently have something like the below but keep thinking of edge cases and my calculations go askew.  I figuring someone must have already done this somewhere but cannot find a lib to look at/use.

```
public class PagedItems<T>
{
    public PagedItems()
    {
    }

    public PagedItems(int offset, int totalSize, IEnumerable<T> subset)
    {
        this.Offset = offset;
        this.TotalSize = totalSize;
        this.Data = subset;
        this.Links = new Dictionary<string, Uri>();

        var pageCount = (totalSize - offset) / 20;

        if (offset > 20)
        {
            this.Links.Add("prev", new Uri($"/accounts?skip={offset - 20}"));
        }

        if (offset < (totalSize - offset))
        {
            this.Links.Add("last", new Uri($"/accounts/skip={totalSize - 20}"));
        }
    }

    public int Offset { get; }

    public int Size => this.Data.Count();

    public int TotalSize { get; }

    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; }

    public Dictionary<string, Uri> Links { get; }
}
```

Comment: Not helpful to your question, but I think this class is trying to do too much - it shouldn't contain anything to do with URLs, that should be in your presentation layer.

Comment: This class is returned from an API

Comment: So? That's still nothing to do with the presentation layer.

Comment: Are you trying to implement an OData provider? Regardless, this might be helpful: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/d02bc61ea7b31ada1e54abbeebbecb3c5df0e3ac/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/GetNextPageHelper.cs

Comment: @DavidG there is no presentation layer. the response shows the subset of data and links to follow the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting this I got it working with this code and unit tests around the logic:

```
public class PagedItems<T>
{
    private readonly int pageSize;

    public PagedItems()
    {
    }

    public PagedItems(int offset, int pageSize, int totalSize, IEnumerable<T> subset, Uri baseUri)
    {
        this.Offset = offset;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
        this.TotalSize = totalSize;
        this.Data = subset;
        this.Links = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (ShouldDisplayPrevAndFirstLink(offset))
        {
            var linkValue = Math.Max(offset - pageSize, 0);

            var link = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseUri.OriginalString, "skip", linkValue.ToString());

            this.Links.Add("prev", link);
        }

        if (ShouldDisplayNextAndLastLink(offset, totalSize, pageSize))
        {
            var linkValue = offset + pageSize;

            var link = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseUri.OriginalString, "skip", linkValue.ToString());

            this.Links.Add("next", link);
        }

        if (ShouldDisplayPrevAndFirstLink(offset))
        {
            var link = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseUri.OriginalString, "skip", "0");

            this.Links.Add("first", link);
        }

        if (ShouldDisplayNextAndLastLink(offset, totalSize, pageSize))
        {
            var linkValue = totalSize - pageSize;

            var link = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseUri.OriginalString, "skip", linkValue.ToString());

            this.Links.Add("last", link);
        }
    }

    private static bool ShouldDisplayNextAndLastLink(int offset, int totalSize, int pageSize) => offset < totalSize - pageSize;

    private static bool ShouldDisplayPrevAndFirstLink(int offset) => offset > 0;

    public int Offset { get; }

    public int Size => this.Data.Count();

    public int TotalSize { get; }

    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Links { get; }
}
```